# Unable to access CiviCRM remotely

Tags: wordpress, installation

We are a having an issue where we are unable to access the CiviCRM feature outside of the server. When we try to access CiviCRM as a domain user on another machine, we are only able to access WordPress features such as Dashboard and Posts but not CiviCRM. When we click on CiviCRM, we get a blank page with some error message stating "System Status: Error". We are currently running CiviCRM version 4.7.10. The operating system is Window Server 2012 R2. We are running WordPress 4.5.3. IIS has been configured to run WordPress and CiviCRM. Any suggestion?

- Konechi Tagawa

Comment: Have you checked the logs for Wordpress and CiviCRM to see if there are any clues there?